# Python цикл while

Tags: python, while

У меня есть вот такой простой код и в нем два цикла для того чтобы при отключении клиента он мог подключится обратно но я хочу чтобы по команде exit полностью завершился весь скрипт но 1 цикл просто не даст этого сделать, что можно сдеалать и изменить чтобы можно было завершить скрипт или завершить сразу 2 цикла

```
def start_anigilation():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 4444
    server.bind((host, port))
    server.listen(2)
    while True:
        try:
            client, addr = server.accept()
            print(client)
            while True:
                message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message == 'user-exit':
                    break
                elif message == 'hi':
                    print(message)
                    client.send('Hello'.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    break
        except:
            break
```

Код клиента

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 4444
client.connect((host, port))


def main():
    commands = str(input('>>> ')).encode('utf-8')
    if commands == 'exit':
        raise SystemExit
    elif commands == 'user-exit':
        client.send('user-exit'.encode('utf-8'))
    else:
        pass

main()
```

Comment: Если скрипт завершиться то сервер уничтожится для всех Вы точно этого хотите?

Comment: один из вариантов убить процесс — `os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGHUP)` нужен импорт `os` и `signal` соответсвенно

Comment: К сожаления это не помогло даже без блока try except

Comment: тогда по старинке — вместо `True` в верхнем цикле переменную заводите (до цикла с значением `True`) а сетите ее перед `break` в `False`

Comment: Я непонял ваш ответ что нужно сделать извините можно подробнее?

Comment: Дополнил ответ, проверил у себя — работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `True` в верхнем цикле заводим переменную `server_running` с значением `True`, перед `break` переводим ее в `False`

```
def start_anigilation():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 4444
    server.bind((host, port))
    server.listen(2)
    server_running = True
    while server_running:
        try:
            client, addr = server.accept()
            print(client)
            while True:
                message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message == 'user-exit':
                    server_running = False   
                    break
                elif message == 'hi':
                    print(message)
                    client.send('Hello'.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    break
        except:
            break
```

В приведеном коде клиента есть ошибка в строке:

```
commands = str(input('>>> ')).encode('utf-8')
```

Дело в том что произведя энкодинг тут мы не получим четкого сравнения в условии:

```
commands == 'user-exit':
```

По этой причине энкодинг при вводе делать не стоит.

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 4444
client.connect((host, port))


def main():
    commands = str(input('>>> '))
    if commands == 'exit':
        raise SystemExit
    elif commands == 'user-exit':
        client.send('user-exit'.encode('utf-8'))
    else:
        pass

main()
```

Comment: Незнаю почему но даже в таком случае цикл не завершился, я уже пробовал так делать но не помогло поэтому спросил сдесь

Comment: Приведите код `клиента` вероятно причина в другом

Comment: Выше добавил код клиента

Comment: Да ошибка в коде клиента

Comment: Да действительно теперь работает спасибо что есть такие люди которые всегда помогут!

Comment: Если можете поставить галочку напротив ответа, поставьте.

Comment: Да конечно уже поставил!

Comment: Спасибо, удачи в освоении сокетов!

Comment: И вам большое спасибо!